# Can I travel to Ireland for a holiday on a business visa?

Tags: visas, ireland, tourist-visas, change-purpose-of-travel

I have a valid multiple entry short term stay (C) visa for Ireland. The "remarks" section on the visa states (among other things) "business". Can I use this visa to travel to Ireland for a short holiday, or do I need to apply for a separate visa for the purpose of tourism?

Comment: If I were you I would ask at the consulate. Have you already tried that?

Comment: @infrared apologies then, will delete my comments. +1 btw

Answer (score 2):

The information on the [INIS website](http://www.inis.gov.ie/) doesn't seem to be very clear about this. The pages for [business visas](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Business%20Visa) and [visit visas](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Visit%20Tourist) both list what you can't do while visiting Ireland on them but don't seem to mention what is permitted. The business visa for example says:

> You are not permitted to:
>
> - undertake other paid or unpaid work,
> - access any public funds.

This would lead me to believe that it would be fine to visit Ireland for tourism but that is pure speculation on my behalf. The best thing to do would be to double check with your [local Irish embassy](https://www.dfa.ie/embassies/irish-embassies-abroad/) before making any plans.

Answer (score -5):

Stay within the allowed times and you should be fine, anything you could possibly do here is business to someone, somewhere.

Comment: You are basically suggesting that the OP should lie to the immigration officer.

Comment: No, not what I meant. I work here and have worked selling incentive tours to Ireland. There is a massive push, from the government, to get business travelers to Ireland FOR tourism dollars. For this reason I don't think its necessary to lie to immigration officers (of which there are none).

Comment: No immigration officers? Those dudes in uniform were from the circus?